# Select single table row from bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I need to be able to select a row in a table by clicking it (and using css class for highlight styling)

```js
$("#infoTable tr").click(function() {
  var selected = $(this).hasClass("highlight");
  $("#infoTable tr").removeClass("highlight");
  if (!selected)
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table id="infoTable" class="table table-fixed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-3">Name</th>
        <th class="col-xs-3">Age</th>
        <th class="col-xs-6">Occupation</th>
        <th class="col-xs-6">Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="clickableRow">
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">43</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">School Teacher</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">$43,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickableRow">
        <td class="col-xs-3">Tim</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">52</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">Plumber</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">$55,000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

my files:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
```

but it does nothing. Any help is appreciated, Thank You!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this like:

```js
$('#infoTable').on('click', 'tbody tr', function(event) {
  $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
});
```

```css
.table tbody tr.highlight td {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <table id="infoTable" class="table table-fixed table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-3">Name</th>
        <th class="col-xs-3">Age</th>
        <th class="col-xs-6">Occupation</th>
        <th class="col-xs-6">Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="clickableRow">
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">43</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">School Teacher</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">$43,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickableRow">
        <td class="col-xs-3">Tim</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">52</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">Plumber</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">$55,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickableRow">
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">43</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">School Teacher</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">$43,000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: any idea why my jQuery wont work? im not getting an error but nothing is happening on my end

Comment: Styling for `highlight` class is not properly declared, maybe?

Comment: it is, can you check my files in the initial question, and tell me if they need to be in a certain order or something

Comment: You can try to put the main css after bootstrap css and also try to add `!important` to `highlight` class `background-color` property.

Comment: still doesnt work :/ been having this problem all day

Comment: can you share the `highlight` class css in the main post?

Comment: i am using the one you put in your answer

Comment: the "highlight" class is not being added to the table rows, the problem is in the jQuery

Comment: Is this demo working for you? And the same code and css is not working on your end?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#infoTable tr").click(function() {

      $(".clickableRow").on("click",function(){
       $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
      $(this).addClass("highlight");
      
      });
});
```

```css
.highlight{
background-color:yellow;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
      <table id="infoTable" class="table table-fixed">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="col-xs-3">Name</th>
            <th class="col-xs-3">Age</th>
            <th class="col-xs-6">Occupation</th>
            <th class="col-xs-6">Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="clickableRow">
            <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
            <td class="col-xs-3">43</td>
            <td class="col-xs-6">School Teacher</td>
            <td class="col-xs-6">$43,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="clickableRow">
            <td class="col-xs-3">Tim</td>
            <td class="col-xs-3">52</td>
            <td class="col-xs-6">Plumber</td>
            <td class="col-xs-6">$55,000</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#infoTable tbody tr").click(function() {
    var selected = $(this).hasClass("highlight");
    $("#infoTable tr").removeClass("highlight");
    if (!selected)
      $(this).addClass("highlight");
  });
});
```

```css
#infoTable .highlight td{
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table id="infoTable" class="table table-fixed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-3">Name</th>
        <th class="col-xs-3">Age</th>
        <th class="col-xs-6">Occupation</th>
        <th class="col-xs-6">Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="clickableRow">
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">43</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">School Teacher</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">$43,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickableRow">
        <td class="col-xs-3">Tim</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">52</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">Plumber</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">$55,000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: any idea why none of my jQuery works? i have it included into my html, i dont get any errors, but the above code does not work for me

Comment: i copied ur jquery to my js file, and its not working, but im not getting any errors which leads me to believe that i am either 1. Using jQuery before it loads, or 2. Not including them in my html in the right order, any idea of a fix?

Comment: @Michael Did you fix your CSS also?

Comment: @Michael Try to check that your js is work. For example, add `alert('test');` at `click` event.

Comment: yes, my javascript works, the problem seems to be with jQuery

Comment: i added my files to the initial question, could you please look at it and tell me if theres any specific order required

Comment: @Michael when you clicked, can you see that class `highlight` is added?

Comment: it is not adding the class

Comment: it works!! thank you so very much for your help, i am new to jQuery.

Comment: @Michael It's my pleasure :)